# Is there something faster than 3D array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I ask this question because I have no idea of what class/api to use to achievement what I want.

I have 2 string association, but I need a way that doesnt require to know these 2 association string value to be called via a 3rd value.

I thought of a 3d array first, but I wanted to know if there was something faster and already built to be used in C#. I thought of a Dictionnary at first, but figured you had to know the key value.

So any idea?

EDIT: Here more details...

I have for example a list of

apple, apple juice
banana, banana juice
orange, citrus juice
lemon, citrus juice
...

Now within another programme there is the fruits and I need to transform them into the appropriate juice. So i need to go throu all the list.

Comment: A `Dictionary`, multiple `Dictionary`s, or something similar is probably the way to go, but we need more details to decide.

Comment: I have no idea what a 3d array has to do with the other stuff you described? An improved description perhaps even with your current code ideas would be nice.

Comment: a 3 dimensions array. Anyway, it seems a dictionnary would do the job so i will use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the key to iterate through a dictionary. However, the order in which you'll recieve the information will most likely not be the same as the one you entered it into if you only use the value.

that being said, can you be most specific about your need. I'm not sure I understand what you want to do.

Comment: The order doesnt matter much. All i need is to be able to go throu the associations

Comment: Is there a forward iterator with Dictionnary?

Comment: A dictionnary will have a values and a keys collection which can be used with an iterator. However, a dictionnay have no order whatsoever, so it doesn't directly have one.

Answer (score 3):

> there is the fruits and I need to
>   transform them into the appropriate
>   juice.

This sounds to me like you have a **key** (the fruit) and you want to get its corresponding **value** (the fruit juice). Then all you need is a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

**The below code has been updated since I first posted.**

```
// OK, so we'll say this comes from an external program. I am just constructing
// it here for illustration.
var fruitJuices = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Apple", "Apple juice" },
    { "Banana", "Banana juice" }
    /* etc. */
};

// This list comes from the user.
List<string> fruits = GetFruitsFromUser();

foreach (string fruit in fruits)
{
    string matchingFruitJuice;
    if (fruitJuices.TryGetValue(fruit, out matchingFruitJuice))
    {
        // Do whatever you need with this juice.
        CreateFlavor(matchingFruitJuice);
    }
    else
    {
        // Either report on the non-existence of this flavor of juice,
        // or possibly just do nothing.
    }
}
```

The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class is implemented as a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which has very efficient O(1) key lookups.

Out of curiosity, what was your plan for using a 3D array?

Comment: Because I can't call fruitJuices[fruit]. I have to go throu the dictionnary without knowing the key name.

Comment: @Wildhorn: You said "within another programme there is the fruits"; what did you mean by that, if you don't know them? I assumed you meant, e.g., the other program supplies `string` values.

Comment: Yeah, well its hard to explain. There is a list provided by a user, that will check if the appropriate fruit is in the other program and if yes, will make the juice, if not, do nothing. But me, I dont know the amount of juice recipe there is, neither the flavor. So I need a way to iterate throu the list of fruit/juice association.

Comment: @Wildhorn: I'm still not seeing why you need to iterate. It seems to me that for every `fruit` in the list supplied by the user, you can call `fruitJuices.TryGetValue(fruit, out fruitJuice)` and do as you said: "if the appropriate fruit is [present] make the juice, if not [the method returns `false`] do nothing."

Comment: Yes the list is provided but I mean, should I use a string array over that to iterate throu the fruit list? That is why I asked if Dictionnary was good, because I didnt want to have to use 2 seperate things.

Comment: @Wildhorn: We're talking about two completely different collections, one from the user and another from a separate program. Right? Why do you want to combine these into one data structure?

Comment: No, there is 1 data collections, but the key/value association come from the user and vary. So I need a ways to iterate throu these association to send to the other program the appropriate values. But what you provided is good. I need the Dictionnary + a list of the keys (was hoping for a class or something allowing me to iterate throu it without the need of a key list)

Comment: I think I fully understand now. You would like to be able to be aboe to do A('orange',AS_KEY) and get orange juice, but you would also like to do A('Orange Juice',AS_VALUE) and get Orange back. As far as I know, there is no data type that does that, but I don't think it would be too complicated to create such things using two dictionnary.